# Unpack 3 and 6 byte two's complement integer in Python

Tags: python, twos-complement

How can I convert 3 and 6 byte big-endian two's complement Python `bytes` instances to Python `int`s?

I was hoping to use struct, but looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters, there are no 3 or 6 byte-long sizes.

Context: writing code to parse SQLite files, and it uses this representation in some cases https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#record_format

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't know about `int.from_bytes`! Feel free to make an answer...

Comment: And why not use the `sqlite3` module to use SQLite files?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ah so I'm writing a streaming parser, to extract rows from a SQLite file while it's being downloaded